# data.dol.gov filters in R

Tags: api, data.gov, labor

I am making a data call against the data.dol.gov API using R and the following works:

```
apikey = ####
query = "https://data.dol.gov/get/violation/limit/8/" 
getdata <- GET(url=query,add_headers("X-API-KEY"=apikey)) 
results <- fromJSON(content(getdata,type="text"))
```

However, when I try to add filters, they don't appear to work.  I'm following what was provided in the developers
http://developer.dol.gov/accessing-the-apis-using-http-requests/

Using the following command:

```
query = "https://data.dol.gov/get/violation/limit/8/issuance_date/start_date/2010-03-15/end_date/2015-04-15"
```

this does not work, even though I feel like i'm following what was provided in the developer's guide.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: this would be a correct link for the API endpoint https://developer.dol.gov/health-and-safety/dol-osha-enforcement/#osha_violation